# Instagram API onpost event

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, discord.js, instagram

I'm trying to create a discord bot (discord.js) where the bot sends a message when an Instagram account has posted something, but I can't find it in Instagram's API or in any other API.
I searched on `npm` library but couldn't find anything either.
Are there any other suitable options for this job?

All I want is something like

```js
let i = require("module-name");

const ig = new i();

ig.on("newPost", (post) => {
    //Blah blah
});
```

I'm using NodeJS and Discord
If I get an API from a different language, I can code a wrapper. So all I need is an API suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

you can take a look at the [instagram-web-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/instagram-web-api) module.

Comment: I did look at `instagram-web-api` and I surely wasn't looking for this